# Far less question regarding Kubuntu, Xubuntu as compared to Ubuntu on askubuntu

Tags: discussion

I rarely see any questions regarding Kubuntu, Xubuntu and so on. Does it mean that these operating systems are also rarely used as compared to Ubuntu, resulting in less questions on the main site?

Comment: That's not really the type of question for Meta.

Comment: I beg to disagree, it is not askubuntu question definitely

Comment: Meta is for questions about the corresponding site, not for questions related to the subject of the site.

Comment: [Meta Ask Ubuntu is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Ask Ubuntu rather than discussing Ubuntu itself.](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @Zacharee1 I think this is on topic, it ask why something happens on Askubuntu, and that is what meta is for, the wording could be a bit better but essentially it is "why do we see a lot of X and less of Y".

Comment: @MarkKirby but the actual question is "are Kubuntu and Xubuntu used less," which is just using statistics from AskUbuntu. It's not asking why there are fewer of those questions, it's asking if there are fewer people using those other flavors.

Comment: @Zacharee1 To me it asks "Why are there less questions about X & K on Ask Ubuntu" I am sure  that is what rancho is asking, I edited it a bit to make it fit better.

Comment: @MarkKirby I still don't think it's about how Ask Ubuntu works.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Well, thats what close votes are for :) Our individual opinions don't matter to much, the voters will decide.

Comment: @MarkKirby well that's why I CVed :p.

Comment: @MarkKirby Well your edit has made it on-topic now. It remains to be seen if that was what rancho intended.

Comment: Of course the edit is good one, I do appreciate the answer by MarkKirby

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO it is just that most questions are independent of the desktop, they are about specific applications or the underlying OS, rather than the desktop, so they appear to be about Unity Ubuntu but the OP may have a different distribution.

Looking through the tags:

Xubuntu has 3081 questions and XFCE 1085

Kubuntu has 2544 questions and KDE has 1422

Ubuntu Gnome has questions 346 and Gnome has 5496

Lubuntu has 2789 questions and LXDE has 355

Ubuntu Mate has 183 questions and mate has 380

This is a rough estimate as there are many more desktop related tags but there are plenty of questions about different versions.

Ubuntu is, of course, the most popular because it is the "brand name" edition and where new users go first but I would not say they are rarely used, just it tend to be more experienced users who try other distributions and they also tend to ask a lot less questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not currently a member of the Xubuntu leadership but brought up the issue of utilizing AskUbuntu during that previous period.  I'm still trying to sort through mis-tagging of questions that drag them under the Xubuntu tag when they don't actually belong there.  That's on my own, though.

Xubuntu's leadership generally doesn't respond to questions on AskUbuntu due to a lack of human capital to spend on it.  There is only so much time to go around.  My own involvement here involves me disappearing for periods as I have other things I have to be doing, too.

Comment: I've seen quite a few questions tagged with Lubuntu, Kubuntu, or Xubuntu when there's nothing at all in the question related to those environments. I may remove those tags and supply something more appropriate.